# Load the Unpacked Extension But It does not work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was trying to incorporate something like Nicholas Cage into one of my projects related to google extension. My confusion is when I loaded the extension on google chrome, it seems that it did not load the jpg file related to Nicholas on my chrome. It supposed to work in the same way as the extension on the google chrome app store's Nicholas Cage. Here is [my code for the nicholas cage.](https://github.com/Fortyseven/nCage)  Here is my manifest json file:

```
  {
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["ncage.min.js", "ncage.js"],
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],
"manifest_version": 2}
```

Comment: You did not specify any permissions for your extension. Start by looking at that.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Comment: That manifest looks perfectly fine. One weird thing is maybe you repeat the same script twice - in minimized form and in its original. But you forgot to load jquery.js and the first script is using it. There's also no need to create a script element in the page in the second script. Learn how to debug your extension's content script (in short: open a web page, open devtools, open the sources sub-panel, switch to the content scripts sub-sub-panel, find yours, set breakpoints, reload the web page and see what happens, inspect stuff, etc.)